# Spring import conflict: multiple jars with same name context

Tags: java, spring, classpath

It's not a very common situation, but I have a maven module (actually for tests, not important) with spring context which should import another context from dependency, however there is another dependency with the same context name.

```
test module
  test-context import beans.xml
under test jar
  has beans.xml
another dependency jar
  has beans.xml
```

`<import resource="classpath:beans.xml`/> loads first context in classpath and it's not the right one :)

Is there any way to resolve the conflict without changing context names or their location? I.e. basically I would like to exclude one jar from resource classpath resolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will reserve negative answer as I think that there is no way other than moving/renaming files because from the spring standpoint both jars in classpath have the same priority, so the first one wins.

Also, I don't think there is a way to exclude jar from classpath resolving as jar file name may be different depending on dependency version for example and it is completely managed by maven, not by spring.

There is one brutal way though - repackage dependency jar on the fly by some maven plugin removing beans.xml from it.

Comment: the first one wins means? Which xml will be picked up in that case?

Comment: It depends on the order of classpath which can be different in different OS, so it's not reliable trying to predict which one will win. As far as I know you can also write import classpath:*beans.xml but I am not sure if it's going to load both files. (Note start before file name)